# JavaScript won't render in browser

Tags: javascript, server, project

I have an issue loading a lot of my JS projects in my browser. I've doubled checked the code on all of them and it still won't work.
I need to upload projects to show in my portfolio but I can't do that if a bunch of my projects won't work!
I always get a message saying that there's a server 8080 or 8000 port error but I don't know how to troubleshoot that. I only know how to work the command line for Github but not to install software or operating system updates. Please help.

Comment: Please add more information. What's the command you are trying to run? What's the error? Which OS are you running?

Comment: Are you sure that the server on 8080 is an error? I think you are mistaking useful info for error messages. Also, what do you mean by "issue loading a lot of my JS projects in my browser" and the GitHub command line?

Comment: You'll need to show the code that is giving the error along with the full error message. debugging Port errors is simple. Are you trying to get something from some port at some host? Does that host serve what you at the specified port, if not, there's the issue

Comment: @Bravo I am not saying anything specific about 8000, just that 8000 and 8080 are being correlated with an error. I am saying that not everything in a CLI output is an error.

Comment: I'm not trying to run a command but I think my issues loading JS in my browser have something to do with my OS or my Firewall server. I'm new to programming and I thought that my OS or server software might be affecting Javascript in my browser. I was asking an innocent question....

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with the ports or CLI. There's this one project in particular that won't render JS.

Comment: I can't attach my JS file or copy and paste it here so I really don't know what to do now...

Comment: Could anyone give me tips on how I could at least troubleshoot this on my own? I'm REALLY frustrated...

Answer (score -2):

The situation is as follows

1: Cross domain problem (solution: set jsonp to solve it)

2: Multi project packaging and on-line problem (solution: integrate the project into multiple projects and package and on-line at the same time. All projects need to be transformed to change the method)

Comment: Do you have the info on the problem? I am not saying that this is a bad answer, just that it seems like you have more info on this problem.